# AWS Serverless node app user role permission: forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am following a tutorial [from here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/angular-universal-javascript-node-js-aws-lambda). I built a basic site, installed the modules, got aws cli working and deployed everything, however when I try to access the site I get `403 Forbidden`. I assume I screwed up the AWS permissions up, but I don't know how to troubleshoot them. Any suggestions?

According to the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html#api-as-lambda-proxy-setup-iam-role-policies) I need:

I created the lambda_invoke assume api gateway role and confirmed:

1) role permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

2) Role trusted access:

```
Trusted entities
The identity provider(s) apigateway.amazonaws.com
The identity provider(s) lambda.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If API GW couldn't invoke the Lambda I believe it would throw some kind of *500 Error* (internal error). But since it's *403 Forbidden* it most likely comes from the Lambda, perhaps the request routing is misconfigured?

Check the *Lambda* and *API Gateway* **CloudWatch Logs** to find out more info on what's going on.

Comment: Turns out I found something in the logs that pointed me to a CloudFormation glitch- deleted site and redeployed. Works great